# How to add validation(javascript) in php?

Tags: javascript, php, validation

let say that, i want to my change password in php code then it will validate by the use of javascript.  before it return to my index page or it will popup on index page. how can i do it? any trick that you can suggest? :)

```
<?php
  include('config2.php');
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $val = $_GET['val1'];
    session_start();
    $ak = $_SESSION['autokey'];

    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET password = '". md5($val) ."' WHERE autokey = '$ak'";
    mysql_query($sql);

    header("location:index");
?>
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're hashing your passwords wrong. Instead of md5 use [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash). md5 is NOT suitable for hashing passwords.

Comment: actually that is not my question :|

Comment: Also, you're mixing mysql_* and mysqli_* up. Which one are you actually using? I would hope mysqli since ext/mysql is deprecated.

Comment: I highly recommend taking note on this. Anyways, please post your JavaScript validation as well.

Comment: I know it's not your question. That's why I'm putting it here in the comments section instead of the answers section.

Comment: i dont have a validation that why im asking for help :) i want to put a popup that say if its success or not.

Comment: @mark do you have a very simple example on password_hard()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your code block like this..

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET password = '". md5($val) ."' WHERE autokey = '$ak'";
mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_affected_rows())
{
    echo "<script>alert('Password was successfully changed !');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
} else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Password was not changed');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
}
```

As the comment says.. You are mixing up `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. Change that first.

`Sidenote:` Switching to **`PreparedStatements`** is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !